# Unable to write file to the Server

Tags: java, file, tomcat

I wrote the below code inorder to write an xml output to a file in my Tomcat Server. When I ran the code I get the below error. May I know what is wrong in my code. Thanks in advance. It is supposed to create a directory with name test and then the file test.xml in the path I specified in my server. But, it is not doing doing that and instead it is looking for that path in my local machine

java.io.FileNotFounException: C:\test\test.xml The system cannot find the path specified

```
   // write the content into xml file
                 TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                 Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                 DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

                 StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("/test/test.xml"));
                 transformer.transform(source, result);

                 // Output to console for testing
                 StreamResult consoleResult = new StreamResult(System.out);
                 transformer.transform(source, consoleResult);
```

Comment: Do you have a /tmp directory at the root of your c drive?

Comment: No. I wanted it to write to my Tomcat folder which has a tmp directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice to save temp files on tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775620/best-practice-to-save-temp-files-on-tomcat) That should tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: Do not assume the presence of any directories.  Use [File.createTempFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) instead.  For example, `File.createTempFile("test", ".xml")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Tomcat set value of `java.io.tmpdir` system property to its `tmp` directory. So the following piece of code should create a `File` object pointing to a file in Tomcat tmp:

```
String tempDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
File outputFile = new File(tempDir, "test.xml");
```

Comment: If I want to save it to create some other directory in Tomcat and then save the file in that directory, then what change should I make

Comment: You can calculate file location relative to your application folder in `webapps`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632608/tomcat-actual-path-for-new-file-creation

Comment: While I do not recomment doing this. Tomcat can be started with engine in CATALINA_BASE and runtime configuration and files in CATALINA_HOME. So the details may vary. Also any solution with permanent local file storage is not portable (e.g. when you have several Tomcat instances load balanced)